# returning a void method in my main method

Tags: java

My question is based on returning a Void method on my main method in java the following its my code. Where am I doing wrong?

```
package practiceq3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practiceq3 {

    public void FutureInvestmentValue(double InvestmentAmount, double MontlyInvestmentRate, int Years)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-5s %s \n", "Years", "Investment Value");

        //For loop
        int i;
        int y;
        for(i = 1; i <= Years; i++)
        {
            for (y = 1; y <= 12; y++)
            {
                InvestmentAmount += (InvestmentAmount * MontlyInvestmentRate);
                System.out.printf("%-5d %2f \n", i , InvestmentAmount);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the Investment Amount: ");
        double InvestmentAmount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the Montly investment rate: ");
         double MontlyInvestmentRate = input.nextDouble();
         System.out.print("Enter the Years: " );
         int Years = input.nextInt();
         Practiceq3 m = new Practiceq3();

        // Compilation error here:
        System.out.printf("Investment Value is $%2f", m.FutureInvestmentValue(input.nextDouble(),(input.nextDouble()/1200), Years));
        input.close();
    }

}
```

The compilation fails with the error:

> Error:(34, 78) java: 'void' type not allowed here

Comment: You need to at least tip us off as to where the problem might be. Structurally speaking, your code looks fine.

Comment: ok my problem is on the following line:  System.out.printf("Investment Value is $%2f", m.FutureInvestmentValue(input.nextDouble(),(input.nextDouble()/1200), Years));

Comment: And the problem is, specifically, what?

Answer (score 1):

Your method `FutureInvestmentValue` doesn't return any value, but you are trying to print the (missing) return value from this method:

```
System.out.printf("Investment Value is $%2f", m.FutureInvestmentValue(...));
```

Looking over your code, it's not quite clear how exactly should the method `FutureInvestmentValue` behave - it seems to print the calculated information itself.

Probable solutions would be either:

1. ```
   System.out.println("Investment Value is:");
   m.FutureInvestmentValue(...); // Prints the calculated data itself
   ```
2. Leave the `System.out.printf` line in the `main` method unchanged and modify the `FutureInvestmentValue` to `return` some value instead of printing it.

Comment: yes how do i go about doing that? because i get it that void do not return anything but i became aware that i can access the values in the void. so in this case am super trying everything but nothing is working

Comment: @MendyMercy, please try the suggested `1.` solution, if your assignment asks for a `void` method (based on your comments).

Comment: ok my void method needs to be having the values of Investment amount, montly investment amount and years. but again all this when i do the calculations for my future investment value it must be called

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do one of two things: either return the result from your method or instead of return value, print out the method parameter that you used to store the result.

So either change your FutureInvestmentValue method like this:

```
public double FutureInvestmentValue(double InvestmentAmount, double MontlyInvestmentRate, int Years)
{
    // skip other stuff
    return InvestmentAmount;
}
```

or change your main method to something like this:

```
double value = input.nextDouble();
m.FutureInvestmentValue(value, value/1200, Years);
System.out.printf("Investment Value is $%2f", value);
```

Comment: the question on the assignments needs me to call the void method in the main method

Comment: @MendyMercy then you'll need to change the main method like suggested

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Alex FutureInvestmentValue method is void and hence you are getting error. If you want to print theinvestmentValue in print statement then change the return type of method to double and return InvestmentAmount variable  value.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to answer this question the way the question requested but i also considered what you guys said and at the end i managed to see my mistakes in my code so the following is my answer for the question

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            ClassB con = new ClassB();//this is the object of the class




            System.out.print("Enter the Investment Amount: ");
            double investmentAmount = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("Enter the Montly investment rate: ");
            double montlyInvestmentRate = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("Enter the Years: ");
            int years = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

//this is where we call our void method FutureInvestmentValue(double InvestmentAmount, double MontlyInvestmentRate, int Years)

con.FutureInvestmentValue(investmentAmount ,(montlyInvestmentRate/1200), years);
        } 
    }
}

public class ClassB { 
 public void FutureInvestmentValue(double InvestmentAmount, double MontlyInvestmentRate, int Years)
    {
       System.out.printf("%-5s %s \n", "Years", "Future Value");

        //For loop
        int i;
        double  Fv;
        for(i = 1; i <= Years; i++)
        {   
    //Future value formular A=P(1+i/m)^n*m
                Fv = (InvestmentAmount * Math.pow(1+MontlyInvestmentRate,i*12));
                System.out.printf("%-5d %.2f \n", i , Fv);
        }
    }
}
```